# Как добавить в начало каждой строки файла (>100GB) порядковый номер этой строки с помощью Python?

Tags: python, файлы

**some_file.txt:**

```
one
two
three
...
```

Как оптимально это реализовать в Python не затратив много ресурсов?

```
with open("some_file.txt", "r+") as file:
    for idx, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        print(idx, line.strip())  

        # 1 one 
        # 2 two
        # 3 three
        # ...
```

Comment: Вам распечатать или новый файл? `cat -n some_file.txt`

Comment: Изменить исходный файл

Answer (score 1):

Заменить исходный файл на месте не получится. Только создать копию.

> ```
> cat -n some_file.txt > some_other_file.txt
> ```

Или скрипт на Питоне:

```
import sys

for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, 1):
    print(i, line, end='')
```

> ```
> $ python line_numbers.py < some_file.txt > some_other_file.txt
> ```